# Apache can't serve DocumentRoot : no execute permission error

Tags: apache, centos7

I am trying to migrate a web application from a Slackware config of Apache to a CentOS 7 one. **DocumentRoot** set to **/home/STORAGE** and there is a simple **index.html** file in it for testing. Both **/home/STORAGE** and **index.html** have 777 permissions set, yet Apache reports :

*access to /index.html denied ... because search permissions are missing on a component of the path.*

On the other hand, **phpMyAdmin** works fine, configured with a separate .conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d . I tried using their example to make a .conf file for my app, but it still reports the same error. I don't even know where to start looking here.

EDIT:

I think this has something to do with the user of Apache. It is set to a local user in httpd.conf not to root, but the only pages the server serves are those in directories owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a permission error but a Selinux issue. I decided to use the default /var/www/html for the application but still, had to allow write access to some dirs. Here is what I typed:

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /some/dir/in/var/www/html -R
```

The first time I typed it without -R and the permissions didn't change (check with ls -Z /dir/path). Now it is fine.